# Android notification no data

Tags: android, notifications, builder, extras

Do some apps not use the standard notification constants provided by the notification class?  Specifically for iHeartRadio, when I display the constants to the log everything is null except the album art (EXTRA_SMALL_ICON).

```
02-22 17:54:56.520    8074-8092/com.madwin.carhud I/NLService﹕ onNotificationPosted
02-22 17:54:56.520    8074-8092/com.madwin.carhud I/NLService﹕ Notification package name = com.clearchannel.iheartradio.controller
02-22 17:54:56.520    8074-8092/com.madwin.carhud I/NLService﹕ ID :1    null    com.clearchannel.iheartradio.controller
02-22 17:54:56.520    8074-8092/com.madwin.carhud D/NLService﹕ ***************Notification*****************
PACKAGE_NAME : com.clearchannel.iheartradio.controller
EXTRA_INFO_TEXT : null
EXTRA_LARGE_ICON : 0
EXTRA_LARGE_ICON_BIG : 0
EXTRA_PEOPLE : null
EXTRA_PICTURE : 0
EXTRA_PROGRESS : 0
EXTRA_SMALL_ICON : 2130837894
EXTRA_SUB_TEXT : null
EXTRA_SUMMARY_TEXT : null
EXTRA_TEXT : null
EXTRA_TEXT_LINES : null
EXTRA_TITLE : null
EXTRA_TITLE_BIG : null
```

For pandora I'm able to get the artist and track title from EXTRA_TEXT and EXTRA_TITLE.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly due to the reason that the app is using Custom View to display it's notification content and not using Notification Builder API.